# Gaugeview and preferences

Tags: android, user-interface

I made use of Gaugeview in an android application. [Here is Gaugeview](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView)

Using preferences I have stored values used by Gaugeview, and always using preferences I let the user change some values that customs scale colouring. If I change these values and I press back no changes are done. I need to restart app to see changes. I can I force Gaugeview to redraw itself without restart application?

Comment: Kindly paste some `code` Man!

Comment: Well... at current time I can't post code until Monday... When I will able I'll post some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! 
I've just added a static variable named "changed", set it equal to true, and in wrote my new onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (changed == true) {
        this.recreate();
        changed=false;
        }
}
```